# Substituir dados de uma coluna considerando dados de outra em um DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um DataFrame com duas colunas **B** e **C** em que os dados não tem nenhuma relação, gostaria que os dados em destaque da coluna **C** recebessem o dados em destaque da coluna **B**, considerando o mesmo *índice*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após alteração o DataFrame ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ola, o que vc esta considerando como um dado em destaque? caso seja um valor em especifico pode usar o metodo apply.

Comment: Para o seu caso acredito que ficaria assim
`df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] if x['B'] == 'A' else x['C'] , axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendo bem direto.

### Criando o DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "B": ["um", "dois", "a", "a", "cinco", "seis"], "C": ["a", "b", "outros", "outros", "c", "c"]})

>>> df
   A      B       C
0  1     um       a
1  2   dois       b
2  3      a  outros
3  4      a  outros
4  5  cinco       c
5  6   seis       c
```

### Alterando o valor

```
>>> df.loc[df.B == "a", "C"] = "a"
>>> df
   A      B  C
0  1     um  a
1  2   dois  b
2  3      a  a
3  4      a  a
4  5  cinco  c
5  6   seis  c
>>>
```

### Com auxílio do Numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df['C'] = np.where((df.B == 'a'), 'a', df.C)

>>> df
   A      B  C
0  1     um  a
1  2   dois  b
2  3      a  a
3  4      a  a
4  5  cinco  c
5  6   seis  c
```

Espero que ajude